# HL7.FHIR.R4 (C#): Literal '2020-12-01T23:00:00.000Z' cannot be parsed as a date. (at Bundle.entry[0].resource[0].birthDate[0])

Tags: c#, hl7-fhir

I am quite new in FHIR development, trying to learn by examples (e.g. from Gino Canessa's YouTube channel).
In an attempt to get patients with the name containing 'test' (or anything) from the http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/ server I am getting the following error message:

```
Literal '2020-12-01T23:00:00.000Z' cannot be parsed as a date. (at Bundle.entry[0].resource[0].birthDate[0])
```

If I try to do the same thing with the other public test server (http://vonk.fire.ly) everything functions perfectly. Obviously I am oblivious of some parameter / constraint in the request.
This is my code:

```
using Hl7.Fhir.Model;
using Hl7.Fhir.Rest;
// ...

List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>();

Bundle patientBundle = null;

List<string> criteria   = new List<string>();
criteria.Add($"name={patientName}");

patientBundle = fhirClient.Search<Patient>(criteria.ToArray());

while (patientBundle != null)
{
    foreach (Bundle.EntryComponent entry in patientBundle.Entry)
    {
        if (entry.Resource != null)
        {
            Patient patient = (Patient)entry.Resource;
            patients.Add(patient);
        }
    }

    patientBundle = fhirClient.Continue(patientBundle);
}
```

Comment: What patient name are you using? This is certainly a bug on the server, nothing you could do wrong could make this happen

Comment: Grahame, thanks a lot! The patient's name was, yes, 'test'. I, too, think it is not due to my code, but rather in the SDK's parser, as Ewout also seems to mention. I am an absolute newbie in FHIR matters, but quite a .Net programmer, so I naively wonder why the parser cannot cope with this seemingly very DateTime-like literal. On my client side I can, naturally, simply catch this exception. (Certainly, you cannot protect yourself against all kinds of bad data on a public test server).

Answer (score 3):

The server is serving up an incorrect *date* for the Patient, since it has a time component. So the .NET library is right I think to complain about it.

Comment: Thanks Ewout! See my comment on Grahame's comment above. I am quite in the beginning of my steep learning curve.

Comment: BTW, is there any API documentation for the Hl7.FHIR library (CHM or HTML or anything)? I have not found anything. TIA!

Comment: Found it myself on GitHub: https://github.com/FirelyTeam/firely-net-sdk/tree/develop-stu3/src/Hl7.Fhir.Core/Model (for the Model module). Was not so easy to find, however.

Comment: Hi @Ewout , i am facing problem related to bundle.Timestamp

 bundle.Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;

response: Incorrect data type used for Bundle timestamp

FHIR server, expecting in this format .
An instant in time in the format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss+zz:zz (e.g. 2015-02-07T13:28:17.239+02:00 or 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z)

Comment: 2022-05-31T10:45:53.973601+03:00 , its not generating in the format of INSTANT